Euclidean distance between 4-dimensional vectors
Recently I've been learning about vectors, hence I thought of the following question:
Say I have two 4-dimensional vectors (e.g. a and b).
$$a = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1  \\
a_2 \\
a_3  \\
a_4
\end{pmatrix}, \quad  
b = \begin{pmatrix}
b_1  \\
b_2 \\
b_3  \\
b_4
\end{pmatrix} $$
I'm not very good at geometry, and am unsure of how to calculate the euclidean distance.
So now, what would be the euclidean distance between a and b?

euclidean distance is calculated the same way no matter how many dimensions your space has. also, you are expected to show your attempts at solving the problem, and point out where exactly you got stuck. math.SE is not here to do your homework for you.

The steps to calculate Euclidean distance is 1. open your browser 2. open Google 3. search Euclidean distance formula 4. calculate

@acat3  Thanks! But google didn't work.

View each row of your vector as a dimension. Subtract one vector from the other, so you have a set of lengths for each dimension. The case for the first 2 dimensions is the classic case, yielding diagonal $z1$ in the diagram. But now forget about the first two entries, and think of $z1$ in the context of the next dimension, it is just some side of another 2D right triangle with sides $z1,d3$, and we treat it the same as the first case. You can iterate this process for any number of dimensions past $3$. Practically, we compute the RMS value of the difference vector for the instant solution.

